# If / Elif/ Else Are All Being Run Even When Conditions Not Met

Tags: python, django, function

I currently have a function to return an error message depending on the error code given (an `int`). The issue is that I have everything within a `Try`/`Except`, and everything is getting run... I put some `print`s so they get printed to the console so I can see where this function stops... But it goes all the way to the end and the message ends up being the final definition on the function..

**Code**:

```
# function for processing declined card errors
def declined_card(code):
"""
Take in the processor_response_code and return the proper error.

- processor_response_code supplied by Braintree on declined card
"""
try:
    # codes falling outside of the dictionary
    print "testing 1: " + code
    if 2092 <= code <= 2999:
        message = "Your payment method has been declined. Please contact your bank " \
                "for more information."
    elif code >= 3000:
        print "testing 2: " + code
        message = "There was an issue with the back-end processing network. Please try " \
                "your transaction again. If this issue persists, please contact " \
                "us using the help page."

    # codes within the dictionary
    print "testing 3: " + code
    if error_codes[code]:
        message = error_codes[code]

    return message
except KeyError:
    print "testing 4: " + code
    message = "There has been an error with payment processessing. Please contact us " \
            "using the help page for more information."

    return message
```

Comment: I suspect that `code` is a string, but your tests are comparing it to integers.

Comment: If your `print "testing 1: " + code` line does not produce a `TypeError`, `code` is not an int.

Comment: What a complete overlook... I remodeled my function but didn't convert `code` to a string in this one. *Face palm* Thanks!